# JQuery Autocomplete - Force choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form working with JQuery Autocomplete and it works fairly well. Now I need another element to force a user to select a valid choice in the autocomplete input. The can type whatever they want and everything is filtered by autocomplete. But they have to select something from the served list.
If they don't the inputfield must get blanked. Tried out a few things with change and select to no avail. This is the code of my autocomplete. I saw some examples operation with data instead of source. This seems to make a big difference

```
$(function () {
    $("#sp_name").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 300,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./Search/",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    zoekterm: $("#al").html()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.naam,
                            value: item.naam
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: you can bind `blur` event to your autocomplete input, in your case `$("#sp_name")`, then determine whether it has perfered value or not

Comment: Should I do that with another JSON call? Or is there some other smart way?

Comment: nope, let's assume your `$("#sp_name")` input expect user to select a name from the autocomplete suggestion list, then you can bind `blur` event to your input like `$("#sp_name").blur(function(){ if (!this.value){/* deal with the case user doesn't choose anything*/}});

Comment: What if they input something that's not in the suggestion list?

Comment: i myself usually add a `hidden input` to store the `id` or something of that choice, by determine the `hidden input`, i can tell from whether user choose from the autocomplete list or not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

I am using a local list here, but you can achieve this via json data source too.
Just add a  change event. The only problem this can have is that if user does not click on
the suggestion, it will turn blank (even if user is entering the same text as suggestion).
It will be mandatory for user to click on the suggestion.

```
var list = ["c", "c++", "c#","Basic","Mongo"];

$('#auto').autocomplete({
source: list,

select: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).val(ui.item ? ui.item : " ");},

change: function (event, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
        this.value = '';}
//else { Return your label here }
}
});
```

JsFidle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/sarcastic/7KdZP/112/

```
In your case, Change function would be something like this:

change: function (event, ui)
{
if (!ui.label) { this.value = ''; }
}
```

Comment: I am also following your code and working great. Can you please explain why there is two `select` parameter  with different implementation in autocomplete and what is their necessity .? @Sarcastic

Comment: For anyone wondering...  if you include `select` twice only the second one is used.  The first one can be removed.